# How to collect tweets by geo-location?

Tags: r, nlp, sentiment-analysis, geospatial

I am extracting tweets on brands for sentiment analysis. I am using twitteR package on R. Is there a specific way by which I can only collect tweets from a location ex NY or Paris or Canada etc. I have tried Geocode but here I have to give lat and long data and the vicinity range.

Comment: I'd use a real database like postgres, and query it with an R library. It'll make short work of such filtering and aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

To get location based tweets, you have to specify a location circle with center (lat and long) and radius using [reverse_geocode](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/geo/reverse_geocode).

There is no way to find tweets by setting a polygon or drawing a border.